# ASP .NET core console application on CentOS server drops requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, centos, .net-core

I have an application running with ASP .Net core using console (not a web app, no IIS). On Windows everything is working fine all the time. But when I run it on our server (CentOS 7), then most requests are dropped.

My starting method is :

```
        ...
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddCommandLine(new string[] { $"--server.urls={urls}" })
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Listener>()
            .UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
            .Build();

        host.Start();

        ConsoleKeyInfo key;
        while ((key.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != ConsoleModifiers.Control && key.Key != ConsoleKey.Q)
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey();
        }

        host.Dispose();
```

And the Listener :

```
public class Listener
{
    ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection collections)
    {
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            ...

            context.Response.StatusCode = *** some response code ***

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(context.Response.Body))
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(*** a response ***);
        });
    }
}
```

If a try some request with curl

```
curl -v http://x.x.x.x:1234/
```

Then most of the time I receive :

```
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* connect to x.x.x.x port 1234 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to x.x.x.x port 1234: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to x.x.x.x port 1234: Connection refused
```

But only most of the time, which means that the same command sometimes works.

And also, if I use Postman then it works ~9 times out of 10..

I looked everywhere and I'm really lost, if anyone has an idea please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Nothing to do with ASP .net or CentOS. It was our firewall (which is behind a vpn), the routing rules were set by range of port ex : from ip1 port 10000-10010 -> to ip2 port 10000-10010. So if a message was received on ip1 port 10001 I assumed it would be sent to ip2 port 10001. But no, it was sent to a random port in the range.